# Managing high dimensions in Numpy

Tags: numpy, array-broadcasting

I want to write a function of 4 variables : `f(x1,x2,x3,x4)`, each in a different dimension.

This can be achieved by `f(x1,x2[newaxis],x3[newaxis,newaxis],x4[newaxis,newaxis,newaxis])`.

Do you know a smarter way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [`np.ix_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html)<sup>1</sup>:

```
f(*np.ix_(x1, x2, x3, x4))
```

For example:

```
>>> np.ix_([1, 2, 3], [4, 5])
(array([[1],
        [2],
        [3]]), array([[4, 5]]))
```

<sup><sup>1</sup>Or equivalently, [`np.meshgrid(..., sparse=True, indexing='ij')`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html#numpy.meshgrid)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to reshape each array giving appropriate number of singleton dimensions along the leading axes. To do this across all arrays, we could use a list comprehension.

Thus, one way to handle generic number of input arrays would be -

```
L = [x1,x2,x3,x4]
out = [l.reshape([1]*i + [len(l)]) for i,l in enumerate(L)]
```

Sample run -

```
In [186]: # Initialize input arrays
     ...: x1 = np.random.randint(0,9,(4))
     ...: x2 = np.random.randint(0,9,(2))
     ...: x3 = np.random.randint(0,9,(5))
     ...: x4 = np.random.randint(0,9,(3))
     ...: 

In [187]: A = x1,x2[None],x3[None,None],x4[None,None,None]

In [188]: L = [x1,x2,x3,x4]
     ...: out = [l.reshape([1]*i + [len(l)]) for i,l in enumerate(L)]
     ...: 

In [189]: A
Out[189]: 
(array([2, 1, 1, 1]),
 array([[8, 2]]),
 array([[[0, 3, 5, 8, 7]]]),
 array([[[[6, 7, 0]]]]))

In [190]: out
Out[190]: 
[array([2, 1, 1, 1]),
 array([[8, 2]]),
 array([[[0, 3, 5, 8, 7]]]),
 array([[[[6, 7, 0]]]])]
```

Comment: Thanks Divakar. what I am looking for is something like `f(magic(x1,x2,x3,x4))`, with automatic spreading. Perharps that doesn't exists ....

Comment: @B.M. Well there is `np.ix_(x1,x2,x3,x4)`, but it adds singleton dims into the trailing ones. Other than that, I am not aware of adding into leading axes.

Comment: And `ix_` is written in python, so you can read it and write your variation.

Comment: @B.M. So, did `np.ix_()` work for you? I thought the singleton dimensions requirement in the question were for the leading axes, which isn't what that function does.

Comment: @Divakar. you are right, my question was ill-posed.